# Selecting range of rows with Select by Expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, features, select, qgsexpression

I can't find any similar questions as this. Suppose I have a layer with 20 features, and I only want the first ten.

so something like `"col1" = 1:10` and then columns 1:10 are selected only.

How is this done?

Comment: Are you trying to select the first 10 features, or the first 10 columns in the table?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

`$id > 0 and $id <= 10` will select features 1 to 10. Where `$id` refers to the feature id, not the row. The row is dependent on your sorting and only visual.

Answer (score 4):

This expression shall also do the job:

```
array_contains(generate_series(0, 10), $id)
```